# Deserializing Jersey inputs with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I have service method with signature like this

```
Foo transform(Foo origin, String key){}
```

I want to make it remote using Jersey. Foo should be serialized/deserialized to JSON by Jackson. Also I want to use GET to such kind of requests. I added initParam FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING and it works perfectly fine with taking Foo as a string and then deserializing it. Like

```
@GET
@Path("transform")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})   
Foo transform(@QueryParam("origin") String origin, @QueryParam("key") String key){
     return transform(deserialize(foo), key);
}

Foo transform(Foo origin, String key){}
```

As you can see outputting Foo is perfectly serializable by Jersey using Jackson. But inputting isn't.

> SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with
>   resource and/or provider classes:   SEVERE: Missing dependency for
>   method public Foo Transformer.transform(Foo,java.lang.String) at
>   parameter at index 0
>   SEVERE: Method, public Foo
>   Transformer.transform(Foo,java.lang.String), annotated with GET of
>   resource, class Transformer, is not recognized as valid resource
>   method.

What can I do to prevent Jackson calls by hand?

Comment: Do you have annotations in your Foo class? You may need @XmlRootElement at least

Comment: @Eugenio Cuevas, I have jackson annotations there. And Jersey perfectly recognize them when I return Foo, but doesn't do this when I consume it.

Comment: Shouldn't you annotate the other method properly? with '@Consumes', '@Post', etc? How are you calling the webservice?

Comment: I want to use Get requests instead of Post. Consumes is used only with Post, isn't it? Now I'm using it throw my JerseyTests with specifying Foo instance as serialized queryParam.